# Questions on Notepad Tutorial:

Tags: android, eclipse

URl of page - http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html
Under "Preparing for the Exercise" the instructions say to

1. Download the project exercises archive (.zip).
2. Unpack the archive file to *a suitable location* on your machine.
3. Open the NotepadCodeLab folder.

QUESTION 1 - **What is considered a suitable location?**
I unpacked the samples to.
  -    *c:\Development\NotePadTutorieal*    -
BUT I don't want to modify the files here. Sometimes I need (or just want to) work the tutorial 2 or 3 times from scratch, and would prefer my base files serve as an untouched template, so I can restart from scratch if necessary. I'd like to have the working code for the tutoriel end up where all my other Android Projects are stored at *c:\Development\eclipse...* but weather I select "Create Project from from existing source" - or - "Create project from existing sample" it seems to leave the files where they are, and work on them in suite (modifying what I'd like to keep as a reusable template) - Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance for any helpful comments.
Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just keep two copies? Work on one, and let the other serve as your untouched template.

EDIT: Make a copy of the entire NotePadTutorial folder in c:\Development\eclipse\ and work on it there. Leave the other one untouched.

Comment: If I just make a second (working) copy into the   c:\Development\eclipse.. directory, will it work?

Comment: Yeah, make the copy. Then choose "Create Project from from existing source" and select that copy.

Answer (score 0):

A *suitable location* is anywhere on your system where you have read and write permissions. If you want them in the same place as your other project files, copy the sample project directory to wherever you want it and then select "Create project from existing source".