# Attempting Android Notepad Tutorial - Exercise 1 - More problems

Tags: android, eclipse

This maybe a continuation from 2 of my previous question, or maybe it's a completely unconnected problem.

Previous questions were
[Questions on Notepad Tutorial:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023133/questions-on-notepad-tutorial)
[Can't read ... AndroidManifest.xml - while attempting Android Notepad Tutorial - Exercise 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025152/cant-read-androidmanifest-xml-while-attempting-android-notepad-tutorial)

The tutorial asked you to select "Create project from existing source". My 1st original question was where to copy the template (original source) to and from the answers I received, It looks like I should copy the directory-structure/source under the C:/Development/Eclipse/ directory, so it would look like this
_ C:/Development/Eclipse/Notepadv1/... _

I did that, and then tried to continue the tutorial, but when I got to the part that says to select "Create project from existing source", I received a pair of errors

> C:\Andriod\Andriod-SDK-Windows\AndroidManifest.xml: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Andriod\Andriod-SDK-
>   (Same error prints twice in the Console & WorkSpaceLog

So I posted a second question about the FileNotFoundException:, and received an answer saying to ignore the message, happens all the time... so I deiced to plow forward again. Now I have 2 problem. One of the problems may well be of my own doing, trying to run threw this tutorial dozens of times, and attempting to back out my changes over and over again.

**Problem # 1:**
I once again start to create the Notepadv1 project using "Create Project from Existing Source" (The cant-read-androidmanifest-xml error still appears), but as suggested I just ignore it. I next select "Android 1.5/Platform 1.5 as the Build Target, BUT the field where you enter the Min SDK Version is grayed out, and you can't enter the number 3 there.. The tutorial says to put the number there, but it seems to become grayed out at the same time I select  "Create Project from Existing Source" and get the "cant-read-androidmanifest-xml" error.

**Problem # 2:**
If I click on [Next] twice, or [Finish] once, I get a pop up box with the message "Invalid project description" - - "Reason: Invalid project description"

> [Details>>] "Invalid project description.
>    C:\Development\Eclipse\Notepadv1 overlaps the location of another project: 'Notepadv1'
>   ".

This did not originally happen. There is no mention of the "Notepadv1" in the Package Explorer or Navigator windows, so I can't find any way to remove it, and I have run Clean Projects, exited eclipse and rebooted the machine a few time... in a few different ways.
Any suggestions?  Joe

*P.S. I have not yet accept any of the answers to my last question, because the juries still out. I'm not yet sure they were correct. I'll will make sure I go back and accept an answers, once I figure out what the correct answer is - Joe*

Comment: For Problem #2 - Is there an existing folder called Notepadv1 in C:\Development\Eclipse ? Browse through file explorer instead of Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem 1 is because the androidmanifest.xml is missing.

Problem 2 Notepadv1 already exists in your workspace.

If I were you I would change your workspace to your Documents/My Documents or equivilant folder depending on your OS.  You can do that under File->Switch Workspace->Other.  Then delete what you have under the Eclipse directory.  It could get messy if you update Eclipse or have multiple versions of Eclipse.

Where is this Notepad project?  Is is part of the SDK?  If it is I would use File->Import to copy over to your workspace rather than mess with the SDK copy.  That is probably why the manifest is missing.

If you would like more help let me know.

PS.  You will probably want to reinstall the SDK if the Notepad manifest is missing.

EDIT:

@Joe.  I couldn't say why other tutorials worked and others didn't for definite but using the SDK as a workspace is definitely going to end up being programmatic when you are learning.  My SDK is separate from my workspace.  So, in a brief summary, I would keep the SDK, the Eclipse source and your project workspace in entirely different locations.  And we can start from there if you want more help.

Comment: Trying out the "Change Workspace to a new locations" and go from scratch. All the stuff in the original workspace was a bunch of Eclipse and Android tutorials. - 1st question (asked a while ago) - tutorial says to use File > New > Android Project. and I seem to need to do File > New > Project > Android > Android Project. Did I install something wrong, or was the tutorial abbreviating the task? - Other Android tutorials all worked fine that way... till now.

Comment: @Joe.  it is hard to say without knowing who's tutorials these are.

Comment: Your working late for someone in the UK. OK. I'll just push ahead and see if anything blows up - FYI their the Android Supplied tutorials  Thanks - Joe

Comment: it depends what you call work... i'm having some beers while giving you the benefit of my immaculate wisdom. check the edit to my post btw.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, and just got it working!

1. I have no idea how to fix, I'm still getting the error, but It's not hindering me from continuing, so I'm not worried about it.
2. Is very simple, you shouldn't have copied the Notepadv1 directory into your C:/Development/Eclipse directory, because, when you "Create project from existing source" it copies it there for you.  So, the one it's trying to copy from is getting in the way of where it's trying to copy to.

Hopefully that makes sense, and helps.

Answer (score 0):

Very Simple, you need to clear the workspace... to do this adopt following 2 steps

1. Right click on your project and select Android Tools and now select Fix project properties
2. Select Project from menu and now click on clean.

This will work for sure

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something (I hope)    Problem with that solution: There is NO project called Notepadv1" to clean.
The error msg says that 
C:\Development\Eclipse\Notepadv1 overlaps the location of another project: 'Notepadv1' 
But 'Notepadv1' dose NOT show up in the Package Explorer, or Navagator windows hierarchy, so I can't select it to clean.
Am I missing something (I hope so)?

Answer (score 0):

Re: problem #2...

My apologies if it's inappropriate to cross-post an answer in multiple threads, but it was asked in a couple of places so in the interest of helping novices with the Android environment (of which I'm one) I'm posting it here as well.

I'm using Vista, Eclipse 3.7.0

I don't know what "File | New | Project | Android Project | Create project from existing source" is supposed to do but I couldn't get it to work for a set of unzipped files of a project tutorial I got from elsewhere. I kept getting that error.

I found what did work is:
1) Copy the unzipped file tree for the project to wherever you want it to eventually reside.
2) File | Import | General | Existing Projects into Workspace | Select root directory:
and point it to wherever you put the zipped files, check-box on for the Project that is the one you want, then Finish

Step 2 seems to not actually move the files anywhere (even though the term 'import' implied that to me), but it seems to just make Eclipse aware of where the project is located and it uses the project from that directory.

That seems to work at least for me.